# C++17 decorate lambda or member function with non-capturing lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17, decorator

I'm trying to craft a function that returns a non-capturing lambda (so it can be converted to a function pointer) that decorates an inner function, where the inner function can be either a lambda or a member function pointer.

[Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrWVX0AGTy1MAOWcARpjEINwArKQADqhChOa0do4uytGxZnRePv5OQSHhRpgm6bQMBMzEBInOrpwFRfGl5QSZfoHBoRFCZRVVybVdTS3ZuR0AlEaoDsTIHFI6AMzeyI5YANSa8zZUDrSm8Wwb2JoyAIILSyuY65sEAJ6RmAD6BMTMhEKHx2fai7uX1zYHGZWIRbp9Tuc/g41hsbCwhCIKuCzqcusQHKZVgB1EgAa2C6wA7PpTqsyatvARVgB3PEQSkU0ZE3SrYiYAhTWgU9Z6VacDYszSEgAiXyFovmJJRJwImCckVUsoBzCBqFWLFYqgC7GRKqIqywaFesseTjlVFoECZQql5NZ7M56zC%2BjCwogetQADpvatysAhNbiV87Xa2RziFzODIZDyWV10CAQGanI8LRANVr2KMIPHEzRiNTyuhYYbWHcHu7iP7RodK9XvZ6a5Lg%2BTxQKxSKxadZfLFVdYeWrMwzasbGxM5hdaqDZgjcwTaocuhmBAx5rmNrJ9oAGw6berRcBZeB23kgZmZDquhdUfjjfsdV3zfXYWrXMgfOF4jFzZrie1w9j3bCFSXJMNHU0Z1ILdD0G19KsA2ZFsQ3tcNI2jWNH3XTccwIBMPxIL8fxsUtBzrANaz9AMGybU8yTbZsIU7ECTgZJw3ktE9kOxPECVpYh8WIG0GKlbi0FoG8PRnOdZXQR5AOYF9uLtQ0SHnJ4FIgSCXTdBk8BPVDHTwTD%2BUlIlhVorsTjtcTJOnVTjUwOTkwtJTQJQhz1NNc1aFhPccQE9oQH43Fa0sli7QAeki1YAEksHHW4rxybwrkpNVFNidQH22XZihAbjovWdzViKzzZS0qDXXpehGWZQyI25Aw%2BQFczwus8kytnNSKv83iQmCvF2uKjqyQZCAACoFNTWhIhebNKWteZX3Kpz5OHI9mGA0aKVqyaXNoGa5uIbMAsEvdSF2gglpW7rHOcnztu48DGumi1jogThrV5A6jpeCAQuCS7tFoskio2V9tBkMIO1FU4pHGVhpDCeRXFkeRUGkGwDGaoRJmmfsfk4eQCGkORRnGXEQDCGQVGkbhUbJjHpHkIQQFp0n0fGOBYBgRAUFQeU8HYMgKHTQXImF9pgE4ThtD4YXZWINmIACJnSACbxyluaRidINAnDNegAHlaFYHX0dILB2Oy2Y5CtvA2T2AA3TA2ctzBxFnIE7fkSlCnVkEAleYhbjsLB1ZePAnF1hG%2BFUf0ADU8EwaljYeNG9f4RgNQ4Hg%2BDoAhhDESRLaUWpVHUFAcb0FQ8ACNnIHGVA5vid3WcKWd8ogdxehqUh3CGNoQlqVI4joPuUhicfaCHnJ2n6Tu9joRoensaplGMLuGm6ZpUuGBejF3yf%2Bl3ueRi%2BiYphmZQXkwWZicR5HGctzGpHEAAObcAFpt24VZgDIEvLLT02hVirhroYVYuBCAkB5PMWoo4JZS2IPAr6JMmYU1IFTGmdMpAM1IDHXBaN7Zv1ZuzUgnNyakB5vzSYBBIhAnIJQA2ksRZuHwEQEeBd6BMDYHnXg2di4SEjmyB%2B8hqSvEiLHJ%2BUgUakBIczKQxsgSMKpKgKgqxP4/z/gAoBfJOCgPAXYIWIs0GjAwVzcYCBMDMCwCEK0eCCFENpoo0gZCjAUKoQjSm1NaZIykPMF%2BpCWaUMwbI7QwSlGWPJuMV2yt4ihCAA%3D) for reference, which I'll dissect in the following.

I've come up with two strategies, one for lambdas and the other for member functions. Specifically, for lambdas

```cpp
template <typename Callable>
auto decorate_lambda(Callable&& lambda) {
    static const Callable callable = std::forward<Callable>(lambda);

    return [](auto... args) {
        return 100 + callable(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Saving off the lambda as a `static` allows `callable` to be used in a non-capturing lambda. This is fine because the `decorate_lambda` template instantiation will be unique for each lambda (IIRC).

For member functions the strategy is somewhat different (note the template parameter)

```cpp
template <auto callable>
auto decorate_memfn() {
    return [](auto... args) {
        return 100 + std::mem_fn(callable)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

I can then do something like

```cpp
const auto decorated_lambda =
    decorate_lambda([](int i) { return i + 1; });

const auto decorated_memfn =
    decorate_memfn<&Worker::work>();

int (*lambda_fnptr)(int) = decorated_lambda;
int (*memfn_fnptr)(Worker&, int) = decorated_memfn;
```

resulting in function pointers that can be used e.g. in a C interface (ultimately).

The end result that I would like is to roll `decorate_lambda` and `decorate_memfn` into a single `decorate(lambda_or_memfn)` function (using template specialisation, `if constexpr`, or whatever). E.g.

```cpp
decorate([](int i) { return i + 1; });
decorate(&Worker::work);
```

I.e. essentially I would like to have `decorate_memfn(&Worker::work)` rather than `decorate_memfn<&Worker::work>()`. The problem is that

- Passing a member function pointer as a parameter, rather than template argument, means the member function pointer is no longer considered a static/global variable within `decorate_memfn`.  Is there a way to force the compiler to recognize that a parameter is from a static/global and hence allow it's use within a lambda without capturing?
- Doing something similar to `decorate_lambda` with it's `static` trick  doesn't work for member function pointers because the template instantiation is not necessarily unique (i.e. if two `Callable`s have the same signature).  Maybe there is a way to make it unique, though?

I understand C++20 could help, but unfortunately I'm stuck with C++17.

Any hints much appreciated!

Comment: "*Saving off the lambda as a static allows callable to be used in a non-capturing lambda.*" And what happens when someone calls that with the different function objects that just so happen to have the same type? You cannot, and *should not* force users to specifically use a lambda when calling `decorate_lambda`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yeah it looks like the eventual lambda-specific (or lambda-like) specialisation must be guarded using `is_empty`, necessitating non-capturing lambdas (which is unfortunate but not a deal-breaker), as Passer By mentions in their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `decorate_lambda` is buggy: it silently breaks if you call it with a stateful callable. As a simple check, you could allow callables only if `std::is_empty_v` is true.

---

> The end result that I would like is to roll decorate_lambda and decorate_memfn into a single decorate(lambda_or_memfn) function

You can use `std::integral_constant`

```
template<auto x>
inline constexpr std::integral_constant<decltype(x), x> constant{};

template<typename T, typename F, F T::* x>
auto decorate(std::integral_constant<F T::*, x>)
{
    return [](auto&&... args) {
        return 100 + std::mem_fn(x)(decltype(args)(args)...);
    };
}

auto d = decorate(constant<&Worker::work>);
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a promising direction. When you say "silently breaks if you call it with a stateful callable", I'm not sure what you mean? A lambda with a simple `int` capture seems to work. I can understand that captured pointers/references are dangerous of course.

Good call on `std::is_empty_v` regardless, I'll be able to replace some hand-rolled code with that.

I'll have a play with `std::integral_constant`, maybe there's a way to get it deduced rather than have to wrap the member function explicitly?

Comment: @Dave See what happens if you pass in two callables with the same type but with different state. The wrapping is necessary.